# How to find the expectation of the following complex probability distribution?

Tags: probability-or-statistics

I want to find the expectation of the random variable `UV`. But the following code doesn't return the desired result:

```
    U = TransformedDistribution[
       Max[X, Y], {X \[Distributed] NormalDistribution[μ1, 1], 
        Y \[Distributed] NormalDistribution[μ2, 1]}, 
       Assumptions -> μ1 > 0 && μ2 > 0];
    (*PDF[U,x]*)
    V = TransformedDistribution[
       Min[X, Y], {X \[Distributed] NormalDistribution[μ1, 1], 
        Y \[Distributed] NormalDistribution[μ2, 1]}, 
       Assumptions -> μ1 > 0 && μ2 > 0];
    (*PDF[V,x]*)
    Z = TransformedDistribution[
      u*v, {u \[Distributed] U, v \[Distributed] V}, 
      Assumptions -> μ1 > 0 && μ2 > 0]
    Expectation[z, z \[Distributed] Z]
```

How can I improve my code to get the right results (the answer is $\mu _{1}\mu _{2}$)?

Comment: You've constructed `u` and `v` to be independent of each other.  If that is what you want, then $\mu_1 \mu_2$ is *not* the right answer.  Only if you construct the problem as did @user64494 will the answer be $\mu_1 \mu_2$.  But even then `Min[x,y]*Max[x,y]` is equivalent to `x*y` so using `Min[x,y]*Max[x,y]` seems unnecessarily complicating things.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Optimizing your code, one obtains

```
 Mean[TransformedDistribution[Min[X,Y]*Max[X, Y],{X\[Distributed]NormalDistribution[\[Mu]1,1], 
Y\[Distributed] NormalDistribution[\[Mu]2,1]}]]
(*\[Mu]1 \[Mu]2*)
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I want to know why I can't get this result when I write it separately.

Comment: @Montevideo: Don't know it.

Answer (score 2):

The code that you wrote makes an assumption of independence which you may or may not have intended.  Essentially your code is attempting to find the expected value of the product of $\min{(X_1,X_2)}\times \max{(X_3,X_4)}$ where $X_1, X_2, X_3$ and $X_4$ are all independent random variables with $X_1\sim N(\mu_1,1)$, $X_2\sim N(\mu_2,1)$, $X_3\sim N(\mu_1,1)$, and $X_4\sim N(\mu_2,1)$.  The expectation is not $\mu_1 \mu_2$.

For example, suppose $\mu_1=\mu_2=\mu$.  The expectation can be found in the following manner:

```
U = TransformedDistribution[Max[x1, x2], {x1 \[Distributed] NormalDistribution[μ, 1], 
    x2 \[Distributed] NormalDistribution[μ, 1]}];
V = TransformedDistribution[Min[x3, x4], {x3 \[Distributed] NormalDistribution[μ, 1], 
    x4 \[Distributed] NormalDistribution[μ, 1]}];
μU = Mean[U]
(* 1/Sqrt[π] + μ *)
μV = Mean[V]
(* -(1/Sqrt[π]) + μ *)
μU μV
(* -(1/π) + μ^2 *)
```

For $\mu_1 \neq \mu_2$ one might need to resort to numerical methods.

If you really intended to find the expectation of the random variable $Z=\min{(X_1,X_2)}\times\max{(X_1,X_2)}$, that random variable is equivalent to $X_1 X_2$ and so there's no need to use `Min` and `Max` to obtain the expectation which is $\mu_1 \mu_2$.